# Can I install IIS on Windows 7 home basic?

Tags: iis, windows-7

I have genuine Windows 7 Home Basic on my Dell laptop. However IIS isn't getting installed here.

Is it something this version of Windows 7 can support?

If yes, please let me know how can I get this installed on my OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think IIS Express should work. New version of IIS for development that just shipped with MVC3.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx

Answer (score 0):

IIS install on home premium it is not installed in home basic .U have to upgrade your os to Home Premium